# ASP.NET Regular Expression for Password Field to not contain Username

Tags: asp.net, validation, passwords

In ASP.NET Create Profile Page:

Our Application is collecting Username, Password and Confirm Password entries apart from other details.

What would be the regular expression on the regular expression validator for the Password field to ensure that it does not contain "Username" entered ?

Edit : On Second thoughts, I guess I will have to use a Custom Field Validator.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a regular expression:

```
!password.Text.Contains(userName.Text)
```

Comment: Thx Oded. I was trying to use a regular expression validator to do it. Guess I forgot about Custom Field Validator.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a separate CompareValidator to make sure that they're not the same:

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="Compare1" 
    ControlToValidate="Password" 
    ControlToCompare="UserName" 
    Operator="NotEqual"
    Type="String"
    Text="Failed Validation" 
    runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Nope. This will only work if the values in both controls are _identical_, not if `passwrod` _contains_ `username`.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't see that you were looking for whether the username was contained in the password.